# Does the host operating system know the content of your messages in a messaging applications?

Tags: operating-systems, computer-networks, security

Let's say you are using a messaging application (Microsoft Team, Skype, Telegram,..) on an operating system (Windows, MacOS, Linux). Does the OS know what you are sending or receiving? If yes, how? Assuming that the computer can be setup for monitoring (e.g. company's computer).

Answer (score 1):

If the OS is malicious or compromised, it can monitor everything you're sending or receiving.  As one simple example, it can [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging) every key press, every mouse event, and everything displayed on the screen.  Why?  Because the OS runs at ring 0, it has control over everything else.

Comment: How can it know what I'm receiving if the message is encrypted and only decrypted at application level? If not compromised, can Windows be setup to do so for corporate surveillance?

Comment: @Son, if you view the message, it can view the screen.  The OS can also access all of every application's memory.  Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is basically yes, [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) is a software that manages the computer hardware, resources, and etc, which means the software (that is in a higher level than the OS) (ex: a messaging app), needs to communicate to the OS to fetch / receive data from it's server.

```
[Software] --> [OS] --> [Driver] --> [Hardware (wifi adapter)] --> [Server]
```

In summary, the OS controls everything.

Comment: How about end to end message encryption for example in Whatsapp?

Comment: @Son When the message is displayed to you, it is not encrypted.